# Issue assigning event listeners in a loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have made a custom chrome extension - a bookmark manager. It's working fine, but I am having problems with deleting the links: If 3 links are given, and delete button is clicked on the 2nd one, both 2 and 3 will be removed.

html + js here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Txr9/

Since this is an extension, inline javascript is not available, and it has to be done with an event listener.

the counter and linkContainer are saved locally. This allows for data to persist between ext launches and ensures that all @id are going to be unique.  The idea is that `indexDeleters()` will add a unique eventlistener to each button each time it's called, which will cause it to delete only that row.

Any input is appreciated!

Code as requested (same as in link above):

**js**

```
function addCats() 
{
    var linkCounter = localStorage['counter']
    var catsList = document.getElementById('catsList');
    var linkName = document.getElementById('linkName');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var linkContainer = document.getElementById('linkContainer');
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('linkName').value));
    a.setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com/');
    a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    var deleteLink = document.createElement('img');
    deleteLink.setAttribute('src', 'red_x.png');
    deleteLink.setAttribute('align', 'right');
    deleteLink.setAttribute('id', linkCounter);
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var linkCell = document.createElement('td');
    var xCell = document.createElement('td');
    linkCell.appendChild(a);
    xCell.appendChild(deleteLink);
    xCell.setAttribute('align', 'right');
    tr.appendChild(linkCell);
    tr.appendChild(xCell);
    linkContainer.appendChild(tr);
    catsList.value = '';
    linkName.value = '';
    localStorage['container'] = JSON.stringify(linkContainer.innerHTML);
    indexDeleters();
    linkCounter ++;
    localStorage['counter'] = linkCounter;
}

document.getElementById('addToList').onclick = addCats;
function indexDeleters()
{
    var Xs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var arr = []
    for (var i=0; i<Xs.length; i++)
    {
        arr.push(Xs[i]);
    }
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        var Id = arr[i].getAttribute('id');
        arr[i].addEventListener('click', function(){removeRow(Id);}, false);
    }
}

function removeRow(Id)
{
    console.log('Call to remove id at ' + Id)
    var Table = document.getElementById('linkContainer');
    var Tr = document.getElementById(Id).parentNode.parentNode
    Tr.parentNode.removeChild(Tr);
    localStorage['container'] = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('linkContainer').innerHTML);
}

window.onload = function() 
{
    if (localStorage.getItem('counter') == null)
    {
        localStorage['counter'] = 0
    }
    document.getElementById('linkContainer').innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage['container']);
    indexDeleters();
}
```

**html**

```
<body>
<h2 align="center">Bookmark Manager</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <table id="linkContainer" width="100%"></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap>Display Name:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="linkName"/>
        </td>
        <td nowrap>Cat IDs:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="catsList"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" id="addToList">Add</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: post the code here too

Comment: Here you go, copied from jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for an explanation of the problem.

In your case, you can directly access the DOM element in the event handler, so that it doesn't depend on any loop variable.

```
arr[i].addEventListener('click', function(){removeRow(this.id);}, false);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much and thank you for providing a link.